# Pandas read_fwf error when skiprows is a function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a very large fixed-width-format file and process it section-by-section.

The [docs on `pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) indicate that

[image]

However, I can't seem to make this work.

This little minimal-criminal reproduces the problem. It tries to read a similar file with four rows into two data-frames of two rows each:

```
import pandas as pd
try: from cStringIO import StringIO # for Python2
except ImportError: from io import StringIO # for Python3

content = '''\
  Foo Bar  Baz
_____ ___ ____
  1.0   2    A
  3.0   4    B
  7.0   6    C
 10.0   8    D
'''

widths = [len(s) + 1 for s in content.split('\n')[1].split()]
widths[-1] -= 1

df01 = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(content), 
                   widths=widths, 
                   header=0, 
                   skiprows=[1], 
                   nrows=2)

df23 = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(content), 
                   widths=widths, 
                   header=0, 
                   skiprows=lambda r: 1 <= r <= 3, 
                   nrows=2)
```

This results in the following error (trace elided):

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

In this case I can obviously replace the lambda by the list `[1, 2, 3]`, but this is not practical when I'm trying to skip rows 1–1,999,999 and 3,000,000–11,000,000.

Is this a bug in pandas `read_fwf`? A bug in the docs?

Any suggestion for a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: The error is 99.9% your pandas version, not supporting callbacks. Try updating: `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: Bingo! I was using 0.19.0 and thought that was pretty new!

Comment: I'm facing the same error in pandas 0.22.0 which is the updated version.   df = pd.read_fwf(file_, header=0, skiprows= lambda x:x in [0,25]) doesn't seem to work